# Segmentation fault c++ in>500

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a problem. Once entered in the data of over 500 segmentation fault error occurs.
The error is probably somewhere here.

```
int y = 1, n, m, x = 1, a, b;
cin >> n >> m;

long long tab[ n + 1 ][ n + 1 ];
bool od[ n + 1 ][ n + 1 ];

do
{
    do
    {
        tab[ x ][ y ] = 0;
        od[ x ][ y ] = false;
        y++;
    }
    while( y != n + 1 );

    y = 1;
    x++;
} while( x != n + 1 );
```

Because later it is cin to, which does not occur.

Comment: insert print statements in the do-while loop. I think that would help to debug.

Comment: What are you inputting for `n` and `m`?  Also `long long tab[ n + 1 ][ n + 1 ]` is a variable length array and is not standard in C++

Comment: It tries to access the n + 1 element of tab and od (which doesn't exist) before testing if y = n+1. You either need a while loop, or remove the +1 from the loop conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are stored in the stack section, the size of which is limited.

IN your program, the 2-D array variables are huge. The default stack size in VC++ systems is 1MB. This limit is violated in cases where n>500. That should be the reason for the segmentation fault.

Try allocating memory dynamically, the memory then gets allocated from the heap.

Comment: And if for arrays of type bool is also such a restriction?

Comment: *The default stack size in VC++ systems is 1MB.* -- But the user is not using VC++.  The code would not compile because of the use of illegal C++ syntax.

Comment: I guess you're right because bool array of complicated for n = 500 but for n = 5000 is no longer so sure about that thanks

Comment: Yes @PaulMcKenzie: You might be right. I am just taking VC++ as an example. The user might be using any compiler, but the segmentation fault could be attributed to the reason mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

First, this syntax is not legal C++:

```
int y = 1, n, m, x = 1, a, b;
cin >> n >> m;

long long tab[ n + 1 ][ n + 1 ];
bool od[ n + 1 ][ n + 1 ];
```

Variable length arrays are non-standard.  However, if they were, then more likely you've exceed the default stack size.

Instead, use `C++` proper, not an extension.  Use `std::vector` to create the 2D array.

```
#include <vector>
//...
    int y = 1, n, m, x = 1, a, b;
    cin >> n >> m;

    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> (n+1, std::vector<long long>(n+1));
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> (n+1, std::vector<bool>(n+1));
```

The rest of the code need not be changed (assuming what you posted in your question is the entire code).